# Sample C++ code for Zaber devices

Tags: c++, zaber

It looks like the [serial protocol for Zaber devices](http://www.zaber.com/wiki/Manuals/T-NA#Control_Through_The_RS-232_Serial_Port) is pretty simple to implement, but is there any sample code in C++ available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are writing managed C++, you can use our .NET library DLL just like you would in a C# or Visual Basic project. You can find more information with the [Zaber Console source code](http://www.zaber.com/wiki/Software/Zaber_Console/Source_Code). The examples are all in C# or Visual Basic, but you can do the same things in managed C++.

If you're not writing managed C++, you'll have to write directly to the serial port. We have some [example C code](http://www.zaber.com/software/Zaber_C_Win32_Demo.zip) that will show you how to convert the commands into a byte stream. This snippet prepares the six bytes to write to the serial port.

```
txBuffer[0] = deviceNum;
txBuffer[1] = command;
// Position 2 is LSB; Position 5 is MSB
txBuffer[2] = ( data        & 0x000000FF);
txBuffer[3] = ((data >>  8) & 0x000000FF);
txBuffer[4] = ((data >> 16) & 0x000000FF);
txBuffer[5] = ((data >> 24) & 0x000000FF);
```

This snippet processes six bytes received from the serial port.

```
deviceNum = rxBuffer[0];
command = rxBuffer[1];
// Position 2 is LSB; Position 5 is MSB
data = ( rxBuffer[2]        & 0x000000FF)
     + ((rxBuffer[3] <<  8) & 0x0000FF00)
     + ((rxBuffer[4] << 16) & 0x00FF0000)
     + ((rxBuffer[5] << 24) & 0xFF000000);
```

How you connect to the serial port will probably be different from our example, but the C++ compiler documentation should be able to help you there. Download the example code to see more details, such as a timer to reset the protocol if it gets out of synch.

For more description of the serial communication protocol, see [the user manual](http://www.zaber.com/wiki/Manuals/T-NA#Control_Through_The_RS-232_Serial_Port).

You can also write [Zaber Console scripts](http://www.zaber.com/wiki/Software/Zaber_Console#Scripting_for_non-programmers) using C++, although we haven't yet created a C++ script template.

Answer (score 1):

Watch out for a bear trap with the Zaber protocol: if the microcontroller loses sync with the Zaber motor it can get stuck reading the back half of one packet and the front half of the next (you should use a timer to detect inter-packet timing gap to reset the protocol state machine)

Comment: Sorry you got tripped up by that, Ken. The [example C code](http://www.zaber.com/software/Zaber_C_Win32_Demo.zip) in my answer does include a timer to reset the protocol. I thought it was too much detail for the snippet, though.